# Update from Debian 9.12

Tags: debian, upgrade, raspbian

I want to start using my "linux laptop" after several years - have a Jriver Mediacenter on it, and want to "get up to speed" running with the latest version of the OS/desktop etc. (installed with Raspbian desktop)

Details:

```
hostnamectl
 Operating system: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
 Kernel: Linux 3.16.0-4686-pae 

lsb_release -a
 Discription: Debian GNU/Linux 9.12 (n/a)
```

I have tried to run `apt-get update` and get a ton lines - and many errors abt repositories not available. Unsure abt how to proceed from here - can anybody help?

Comment: Can you provide details about the error?  Can you confirm that you are connected to the internet?  Currently, `stretch` is still available on Debian's main archive, but it will be removed in about a month (2023-04-23 or later).  Between now and then, you should also update your sources.list to point to archive.debian.org.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no absolute need for an upgrade, I would recommend to manually reinstall the latest version instead of upgrading (eg. Debian 11).

1. Boot on your machine with a live media in order to backup your data
2. Install a fresh Debian 11, erasing the old installation on your computer
3. Re-import your data for your backup after the installation finished

I think this is the safest way to have a system working properly.

### In case you want to upgrade

Debian however has really good support for major versions upgrades.
It could be interesting, particularly if you don't have a lot of tweaks on the existing system.

The procedure is:

#### 1. Fully upgrade the system

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt full-upgrade
```

#### 2. Update Debian repositories

Replace old code names by the new ones.
Here is an example for `bullseye` (11):

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main
```

From [here](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList).

#### 3. Update packages from new repositories

```
apt clean
apt update
```

#### 4. Perform major upgrade

```
apt upgrade
apt full-upgrade
```

#### 5. Clean packages and reboot

```
apt autoremove --purge # Purge if you want to remove configuration from removed packages
reboot
```

### Note

As said by @Stewart, this is generally safer to upgrade to each intermediate release using the code name.
In your case:

```
stretch --> buster --> bullseye
```

### Sources

- [Official documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianUpgrade)

Comment: Upgrades from older versions of debian are fully supported.  It should be very possible (and not difficult to upgrade).  Though I would probably recommend upgrading to `buster`, before going to `bullseye`.  Getting the machine to talk to the mirror will probably be OPs biggest hurdle.

Comment: "it is recommended to manually reinstall the latest version instead of upgrading" - citation needed, mate.

Comment: Yep, of course, some users feedback [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5466/is-a-clean-install-better-than-upgrading). A bit old but interesting... It is true that Debian supports well stable versions upgrades, but if possible, my advice is to do clean reinstall, as this is generally safer to start with the os version-specific configuration. Edited my answer as this need to be understood as a personal advice, from my personal experience using debian servers in production.

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade your Debian 9 System to the newest version (11) you need to adjust your package sources under `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

**Important: Backup your data beforehand**

In this file, you have to replace "stretch" with "buster" to first upgrade to Debian Version 10 with `$sudo apt update` followed by `$sudo apt upgrade` and finally `$sudo apt full-upgrade`.

[Source for the first jump](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/update-upgrade-debian-9-to-debian-10-buster/)

The same procedure has to be repeated for the jump from 10 to 11. Instead, now you have to replace "buster" with bullseye.

[Source for the second jump](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/update-upgrade-debian-10-to-debian-11-bullseye/)

However, as thiblcr already mentioned, If you are not running a hard to replicate setup, it's easier just to install Debian 11 as a fresh installation. Before you do that, make a backup of important data like your `/home` directory and `/etc/` for system configurations.

Comment: Have a second, older lap top with same installation - so went for the upgrade. Followed steps for the first jump. Turned out there were also references to jessie in the sources.list - replaced all with buster. When booted into buster upgrade there is problems with logging in with the regular user - old system was set to log in automatically. When logging in as root - everything looks fine and operational, however cannot run the applications i want from root (chrome, media center etc).

Comment: Sorry - new user on forum - used enter key to change lines - and posted - prematurely :-) .... wanted to add that I got the following errors during upgrade;

After bullit 5;

Errors were encountered while processing:
 live-tools
 console-setup-linux
 dphys-swapfile
 E: sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

After bullit 6;

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-4aSWX9/117-chromium_90.0.4430.212-1~deb10u1_i386.deb
 E: sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)